# How to build and deploy nextjs14 project on cpanel?

Tags: next.js, deployment

-my next.config.js file----

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    output: 'export',
}
module.exports = nextConfig
```

--- my command-------
npm run build

I am getting error:

```
Page "/post/[id]" is missing "generateStaticParams()" so it cannot be used with "output: export" config.
```

I want to build without any error and create a folder "out".

Error image:
[image]